# User Rating and Review options in Google Play

Tags: google-play

I published an android game yesterday. Today when I check the game, I haven't found any rating or review option. Again I have checked with my friends' phones, again nothing was found, no rating and review option. Also, I found the installed status to zero in the statistics column of Google Play Developer Services.

Does it take some time to get it available or did I miss something. Please Help.

Comment: I am also having this issue.  Did you ever find a solution?